# REST/json Angular/Grails HTTP PUT (update) "Internal Server Error" 500

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, grails

I had tested a sample app with REST/json/Grails on one end & Angular on one end to proof test the flow. It was working perfectly fine. All of HTTP GET, POST, PUT, & DELETE was fine.

Now I am making JSON requests via REST in a full-blown app for Project Management. It has basic class structure for the app: classes on Project, Contract, Contacts, Projects Roles etc.

While updating any & every record in the database (MySql 5.6 Community, Grails 2.4.3) via HTTP PUT (with PUT only, POSt with identical arguments works perfectly fine) REST/JSON, I am getting the following error (on the client side):

===================================================

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error URI/apaNew/api/v1/projectTasks/3Classjava.lang.NullPointerExceptionMessagenull
Around line 198 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java 195:  if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cacheOperations)) {196:             log.debug("No cacheable annotation found for {}:{} {}",197:                     new Object[] { request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });198: chain.doFilter(request, response);199:                return;200:         }201: 

Around line 63 of AbstractFilter.java 60:       try {61:            // NO_FILTER set for RequestDispatcher forwards to avoid double gzipping62: if (filterNotDisabled(request)) {63:                doFilter(request, response, chain);64:          }65:            else {66:               chain.doFilter(req, res);

Around line 82 of CorsFilter.java 79:                }80:            }81:  }82:        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);83:    }84:85:    private boolean checkOrigin(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

Trace 
Line | Method ->>  198 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|     82 | doFilter  in CorsFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

==============================================

The application is a very simple project management app. It has a Project class whose records I am trying to modify.

It was working absolutely fine in a sample app I had written before to test everything. Only after converting it into a full-blown app the problem has surfaced.

The HTTP POST/GET/DELETE request is working perfectly fine. An HTTP POST request with similar parameters is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Try disabling cache plugin (grails.cache.enabled = false in Config.grooy). or remove the dependency of the cache plugin if you dont plan to use it, and see if that helps. Try hitting the url directly from browser or from some rest api client browser plugin and see. Also, you should not need cors plugin if you dont want to use cross domain ajax, but just expose rest api to android or other rest clients.

Comment: Thx. I will work on the above. & report back.

Comment: @sudhir Disabling the cache plugin removes the cache error. But he "CheckOrigin" error still fails. I am using the REST/PUT call from an Angular client running from NetBeans. Is there a way of disabling the cors plugin. Besides what will I do in a production environment. It's giving a `NullPointerException in doFilter in CorsFilter`.